# Java Lambda Expression and Logging

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, log4j2

I was reading the new features of Log4j2 and there's a feature that enables

**"Java 8 lambda support for lazy logging"**

And it gives two examples

The first one is the bad practice

```
// pre-Java 8 style optimization: explicitly check the log level
// to make sure the expensiveOperation() method is only called if necessary
 if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
  logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", expensiveOperation());
 }
```

And the second one is the good practice

```
// Java-8 style optimization: no need to explicitly check the log level:
// the lambda expression is not evaluated if the TRACE level is not enabled
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", () -> expensiveOperation());
```

Where is being made the checking if the requested log level is enabled ?
`"logger.isTraceEnabled()"` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Where is being made the checking if the requested log level is enabled ?

Inside the `logger.trace()` method.

The trick here however is in the way you pass the argument. Pre-java8 style computed the value at the time of calling `logger.trace`.

```
logger.trace(..., expensiveOperation());
```

Java 8 style uses a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)

```
logger.trace( ..., () -> expensiveOperation());
```

So the `expensiveOperation()` is called only when requested - inside the `trace` method.

Have a look at implementation of `java.util.logging.Logger.log()`:

```
public void log(Level level, Supplier<String> msgSupplier) {
    if (!isLoggable(level)) {
        return;
    }
    LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(level, msgSupplier.get()); // <-- here is the expensive computation
    doLog(lr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `trace` method (or any other logging method for that sake) already checks logging level internally. Checking it in the caller too is an optimization to avoid calculating `expensiveOperation()`. With Java 8's new syntax, we don't pass the calculated value of `expensiveOperation()`, but a lambda that invokes it only if needed.

Note that although log4j didn't implement it, you could, in theory, have the same behavior without the fancy Java 8 syntax by defining an interface for a value provider, and have the logging method call it:

```
// Interface definition
public interface ValueProvider {
    String getValue();
}

// Calling it from the main code with an anonymous implementation:
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}",
             new ValueProvider() {
                 public String getValue() {
                     return expensiveOperation();
                 }
             });
```